# getting credentials entered as invalid even after entering valid credentials in xts-pythonclient-api-sdk

Tags: python-3.x, rest, finance, algorithmic-trading, trading

I am working on algorithmic trading using python with the IIFL securities account for which we are using the xts-pythonclient-api-sdk
I am running the Example.py file

```
#Marketdata API Credentials
 API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"
 API_SECRET = "YOUR_API_SECRET_HERE"
 XTS_API_BASE_URL = "https://developers.symphonyfintech.in"
 source = "WEBAPI"

"""Make the XTSConnect Object with Marketdata API appKey, secretKey and source"""
xt = XTSConnect(API_KEY, API_SECRET, source)

"""Using the object we call the login function Request"""
response = xt.marketdata_login()
print("MarketData Login: ", response)
```

Below I have attached the connect.py file

```
from six.moves.urllib.parse import urljoin
import json
import logging
import requests
import Exception as ex
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
import configparser

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class XTSCommon:
    """
    Base variables class
    """

    def __init__(self, token=None, userID=None, isInvestorClient=None):
        """Initialize the common variables."""
        self.token = token
        self.userID = userID
        self.isInvestorClient = isInvestorClient


class XTSConnect(XTSCommon):
    """
    The XTS Connect API wrapper class.
    In production, you may initialise a single instance of this class per `api_key`.
    """
    """Get the configurations from config.ini"""
    cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cfg.read('config.ini')

    # Default root API endpoint. It's possible to
    # override this by passing the `root` parameter during initialisation.
    _default_root_uri = cfg.get('root_url', 'root')
    _default_login_uri = _default_root_uri + "/user/session"
    _default_timeout = 7  # In seconds

    # SSL Flag
    _ssl_flag = cfg.get('SSL', 'disable_ssl')

    # Constants
    # Products
    PRODUCT_MIS = "MIS"
    PRODUCT_NRML = "NRML"

    # Order types
    ORDER_TYPE_MARKET = "MARKET"
    ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT = "LIMIT"

    # Transaction type
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_BUY = "BUY"
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_SELL = "SELL"

    # Squareoff mode
    SQUAREOFF_DAYWISE = "DayWise"
    SQUAREOFF_NETWISE = "Netwise"

    # Squareoff position quantity types
    SQUAREOFFQUANTITY_EXACTQUANTITY = "ExactQty"
    SQUAREOFFQUANTITY_PERCENTAGE = "Percentage"

    # Validity
    VALIDITY_DAY = "DAY"

    # Exchange Segments
    EXCHANGE_NSECM = "NSECM"
    EXCHANGE_NSEFO = "NSEFO"
    EXCHANGE_NSECD = "NSECD"
    EXCHANGE_MCXFO = "MCXFO"
    EXCHANGE_BSECM = "BSECM"

    # URIs to various calls
    _routes = {
        # Market API endpoints
        "marketdata.prefix": "marketdata",
        "market.login": "/marketdata/auth/login",
        "market.logout": "/marketdata/auth/logout",

        "market.config": "/marketdata/config/clientConfig",

        "market.instruments.master": "/marketdata/instruments/master",
        "market.instruments.subscription": "/marketdata/instruments/subscription",
        "market.instruments.unsubscription": "/marketdata/instruments/subscription",
        "market.instruments.ohlc": "/marketdata/instruments/ohlc",
        "market.instruments.indexlist": "/marketdata/instruments/indexlist",
        "market.instruments.quotes": "/marketdata/instruments/quotes",

        "market.search.instrumentsbyid": '/marketdata/search/instrumentsbyid',
        "market.search.instrumentsbystring": '/marketdata/search/instruments',

        "market.instruments.instrument.series": "/marketdata/instruments/instrument/series",
        "market.instruments.instrument.equitysymbol": "/marketdata/instruments/instrument/symbol",
        "market.instruments.instrument.futuresymbol": "/marketdata/instruments/instrument/futureSymbol",
        "market.instruments.instrument.optionsymbol": "/marketdata/instruments/instrument/optionsymbol",
        "market.instruments.instrument.optiontype": "/marketdata/instruments/instrument/optionType",
        "market.instruments.instrument.expirydate": "/marketdata/instruments/instrument/expiryDate"
    }

    def __init__(self,
                 apiKey,
                 secretKey,
                 source,
                 root=None,
                 debug=False,
                 timeout=None,
                 pool=None,
                 disable_ssl=_ssl_flag):
        """
        Initialise a new XTS Connect client instance.
        - `api_key` is the key issued to you
        - `token` is the token obtained after the login flow. Pre-login, this will default to None,
        but once you have obtained it, you should persist it in a database or session to pass
        to the XTS Connect class initialisation for subsequent requests.
        - `root` is the API end point root. Unless you explicitly
        want to send API requests to a non-default endpoint, this
        can be ignored.
        - `debug`, if set to True, will serialise and print requests
        and responses to stdout.
        - `timeout` is the time (seconds) for which the API client will wait for
        a request to complete before it fails. Defaults to 7 seconds
        - `pool` is manages request pools. It takes a dict of params accepted by HTTPAdapter
        - `disable_ssl` disables the SSL verification while making a request.
        If set requests won't throw SSLError if its set to custom `root` url without SSL.
        """
        self.debug = debug
        self.apiKey = apiKey
        self.secretKey = secretKey
        self.source = source
        self.disable_ssl = disable_ssl
        self.root = root or self._default_root_uri
        self.timeout = timeout or self._default_timeout

        super().__init__()

        # Create requests session only if pool exists. Reuse session
        # for every request. Otherwise create session for each request
        if pool:
            self.reqsession = requests.Session()
            reqadapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(**pool)
            self.reqsession.mount("https://", reqadapter)
        else:
            self.reqsession = requests

        # disable requests SSL warning
        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

    def _set_common_variables(self, access_token, userID, isInvestorClient=None):
        """Set the `access_token` received after a successful authentication."""
        super().__init__(access_token, userID, isInvestorClient)

    def _login_url(self):
        """Get the remote login url to which a user should be redirected to initiate the login flow."""
        return self._default_login_uri

    ########################################################################################################
    # Market data API
    ########################################################################################################

    def marketdata_login(self):
        try:
            params = {
                "appKey": self.apiKey,
                "secretKey": self.secretKey,
                "source": self.source
            }
            response = self._post("market.login", params)

            if "token" in response['result']:
                self._set_common_variables(response['result']['token'], response['result']['userID'])
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            return response['description']


    ########################################################################################################
    # Common Methods
    ########################################################################################################

    def _get(self, route, params=None):
        """Alias for sending a GET request."""
        return self._request(route, "GET", params)

    def _post(self, route, params=None):
        """Alias for sending a POST request."""
        return self._request(route, "POST", params)

    def _put(self, route, params=None):
        """Alias for sending a PUT request."""
        return self._request(route, "PUT", params)

    def _delete(self, route, params=None):
        """Alias for sending a DELETE request."""
        return self._request(route, "DELETE", params)

    def _request(self, route, method, parameters=None):
        """Make an HTTP request."""
        params = parameters if parameters else {}

        # Form a restful URL
        uri = self._routes[route].format(params)
        url = urljoin(self.root, uri)
        headers = {}

        if self.token:
            # set authorization header
            headers.update({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': self.token})

        try:
            r = self.reqsession.request(method,
                                        url,
                                        data=params if method in ["POST", "PUT"] else None,
                                        params=params if method in ["GET", "DELETE"] else None,
                                        headers=headers,
                                        verify=not self.disable_ssl)

        except Exception as e:
            raise e

        if self.debug:
            log.debug("Response: {code} {content}".format(code=r.status_code, content=r.content))

        # Validate the content type.
        if "json" in r.headers["content-type"]:
            try:
                data = json.loads(r.content.decode("utf8"))
            except ValueError:
                raise ex.XTSDataException("Couldn't parse the JSON response received from the server: {content}".format(
                    content=r.content))

            # api error
            if data.get("type"):

                if r.status_code == 400 and data["type"] == "error" and data["description"] == "Invalid Token":
                    raise ex.XTSTokenException(data["description"])

                if r.status_code == 400 and data["type"] == "error" and data["description"] == "Bad Request":
                    message = "Description: " + data["description"] + " errors: " + data['result']["errors"]
                    raise ex.XTSInputException(str(message))

            return data
        else:
            raise ex.XTSDataException("Unknown Content-Type ({content_type}) with response: ({content})".format(
                content_type=r.headers["content-type"],
                content=r.content))
```

**The error that I am getting** :

```
{'type': 'error', 'code': 'e-response-0005', 'description': 'Your credentials are invalid'}
MarketData Login:  Your credentials are invalid
Config : {'type': 'error', 'code': 'e-token-0006', 'description': 'Please Provide token to Authenticate'}
Quote : {'type': 'error', 'code': 'e-token-0006', 'description': 'Please Provide token to Authenticate'}
Subscribe : {'type': 'error', 'code': 'e-token-0006', 'description': 'Please Provide token to Authenticate'}
Unsubscribe : {'type': 'error', 'code': 'e-token-0006', 'description': 'Please Provide token to Authenticate'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Connect.py", line 526, in get_master
    response = self._post('market.instruments.master', json.dumps(params))
  File "Connect.py", line 636, in _post
    return self._request(route, "POST", params)
  File "Connect.py", line 688, in _request
    message = "Description: " + data["description"] + " errors: " + data['result']["errors"]
TypeError: must be str, not list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Example.py", line 199, in <module>
    response = xt.get_master(exchangeSegmentList=exchangesegments)
et_master
    return response['description']
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

For further reference please refer the link below for the **github code**:
https://github.com/symphonyfintech/xts-pythonclient-api-sdk